# How can I call CSS keyframe using Javascript? without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code that blinks the text.

```css
div#b {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0
  }
  ;
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">Blinking</div>
```

I also have a table

```
 <tr>
  <th id="1">Mon</th>
  <th id="2">Tue</th>
  <th id="3">Wed</th>
  <th id="4">Thu</th>
  <th id="5">Fri</th>
</tr>
```

Basically, I want to make Tuesday blink 5 minutes before it is Tuesday etc. on all the days of the week.
So, I want to implement the **@keyframes** blink I made in the above CSS to the each HTML element with different ids.

How can I do this? 
without using jquery. I haven't learned that.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: You should consider learning some jQuery its not very difficult and sounds like it would help you solve some of the issues you are having.

Comment: I would recommend creating another `CSS` class that you will add / remove to show the animation

Comment: Do you want to blink the `li` element in which circumstances?
Do you mean blinking the element `The` five minutes before the 12:00 pm on Mondays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```js
var blinking = document.getElementById("b");
b.className = "blinking";


function RemoveBlink() {
  var blinking = document.getElementById("b");
  b.className = "";
}
```

```css
div#b {
  
}

.blinking {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.0
  }
  ;
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">Blinking</div>

<button onclick="RemoveBlink()">REMOVE BLINK</button>
```